# Selecting hash elements by comparing with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I am looking for the Ruby/Rails way to approach the classic "select items from a set based on matches with another set" task.

Set one is a simple hash, like this:

```
  fruits = {:apples => "red", :oranges => "orange", :mangoes => "yellow", :limes => "green"}
```

Set two is an array, like this:

```
   breakfast_fruits = [:apples, :oranges]
```

The desired outcome is a hash containing the fruits that are listed in Breakfast_fruits:

```
    menu = {:apples => "red", :oranges => "orange"}
```

I've got a basic nested loop going, but am stuck on basic comparison syntax:

```
   menu = {}

   breakfast_fruits.each do |brekky|
      fruits.each do |fruit|
         //if fruit has the same key as brekky put it in menu
      end
   end
```

I'd also love to know if there is a better way to do this in Ruby than nested iterators.

Comment: If you only want the values the `values_at ` function is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Hash#keep_if`:

```
fruits.keep_if { |key| breakfast_fruits.include? key }
# => {:apples=>"red", :oranges=>"orange"}
```

This will modify `fruits` itself. If you don't want that, a little modification of your code works:

```
menu = {}
breakfast_fruits.each do |brekky|
    menu[brekky] = fruits[brekky] if breakfast_fruits.include? brekky
end
```

Comment: Did you forget that `fruits.select...` uses [Hash#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) rather than [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveSupport (which comes with Rails) adds [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice):

> **slice(*keys)**
>
> Slice a hash to include only the given keys. Returns a hash containing the given keys.

So you can say things like:

```
h = { :a => 'a', :b => 'b', :c => 'c' }.slice(:a, :c, :d)
# { :a => 'a', :c => 'c' }
```

In your case, you'd splat the array:

```
menu = fruits.slice(*breakfast_fruits)
```